# Default node type for Node<T>

Tags: neo4jclient

I am starting to investigate the use of Neo4j using the neo4client API.
I have created a basic database, and can query it using the web client. I am now trying to build a sample C# interface. I am having some problems with index lookups. My database consists of nodes with two properties: conceptID and fullySpecifiedName. Auto-indexing is enabled, and both node properties are listed in the node_keys_indexable property of neo4j.properties.

I keep getting IntelliSense errors in my C# when using the Node class. It appears to be defined as `Node<T>`, but I don't know what to supply as the value of the type. Consider this example from this forum...

```
var result = _graphClient
.Cypher
.Start(new
{
    n = Node.ByIndexLookup("index_name", "key_name", "Key_value")
})
.Return((n) => new
{
    N = n.Node<Item>()
})
.Results
.Single();

var n = result.N;
```

Where does the "Item" in `Node<Item>` come from?
I have deduced that the index name I should use is `node_auto_index`, but I can't figure out a default node type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Item` is the type of node you have stored in the DB, so if you have you're storing a class:

```
public class MyType { public int conceptId { get; set; } public string fullySpecifiedName { get;set; } }
```

You would be retrieving `Node<MyType>` back.

Simple flow:

```
//Store a 'MyType'
_graphClient.Create(new MyType{conceptId = 1, fullySpecifiedName = "Name");

//Query MyType by Index
var query = 
    _graphClient.Cypher
        .Start(new { n = Node.ByIndexLookup("node_auto_index", "conceptId", 1)
        .Return<Node<MyType>>("n");

Node<MyType> result = query.Results.Single();

//Get the MyType instance
MyType myType = result.Data;
```

You can bypass the `result.Data` step by doing `.Return<MyType>("n")` instead of `Node<MyType>` as you'll just get an instance of `MyType` in that case.

Comment: Thanks Chris. It is so obvious once some one points it out to you!